# get_pages gives wrong ID for blogpage

Tags: id, pages

I have a problem with get_pages. It displays the wrong ID for the blog page. I have tried this code.

```
$pages = get_pages(array("echo" => 0));
foreach($pages as $page){
    echo $page->ID;
}
```

But for the blog page it returns the wrong ID. It should be 1 (the blog page is automatically 1 if I understand it correctly) but instead it returns the ID of the actual page.

I've also tried the is_page() function, but that doesn't seem to work on objects.

Is there any way arround this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the blog page is just a regular page, it has no special ID number and it can be anything. The only special thing about a blog page is that it was assigned to use as a "blog" page and you can check for its ID value in one of the options.

Comment: Ah wow. wp_reset_postdata was commented. That's why it reported 1 (which is ofcourse the hello world post, doh).

Comment: *can be anything* is ambiguous and wrong

Comment: @PieterGoosen, suggestions on how to make it clearer are welcome. As for the wrong part, I don't get it.

Comment: The blog page ID is not anything, it is the ID of the page that was assigned as blog page as I have stated in my answer;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen, I think you get it backwards ;) first there is a page that can have any ID number and only then it is assigned into the option that include the value of the ID of the blog page :)

Answer (score 1):

The ID of the blog page will be the ID of the page that you assigned as the blog page. This can be very easily be checked by adding the following code in your header

```
var_dump( get_queried_object() )
```

That will dump the entire page object of the page that was used as the blog page. The whole static front page and blog page thing is quite confusing here. Although you created a page in backend and assigned a template to it, once you set that page as a blog page, either `home.php` or `index.php` is used to display the blog page and not the template set when you created that page.

As to why you are thinking the ID should be `1`, I don't know. Would be nice if you can link to some resources